# Alternative of using select query in case when statement in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, subquery

I am trying to run a query with `select` in `case when` statement. something like this:

```
select case when cust_id in (select cust_id from tab_cust) then 'Eligible' else 'Not Eligible' end as Eligibility
from tab_product;
```

but running this query in spark sql is giving error:

> Table or view not found: tab_cust

But if I use same select query as subquery in where, no error is given but that will exclude set of records, which I don't want.

Is there any way to perform this query without using select statement in case when to get the same result?

Comment: When would a non-NULL value of `cust_id` *not* match `tab_cust.cust_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to test if a value in one table is in another table.  True?  I use JOINs for this.  Here is a pyspark example.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

custSchema = StructType([
  StructField("cust_id", IntegerType())
])

productDF = spark.createDataFrame([(1,),
                                   (2,),
                                   (3,)
                                  ], schema=custSchema)

productDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tab_product")

customerDF = spark.createDataFrame([(2,),
                                    (3,),
                                    (4,)
                                  ], schema=custSchema)

customerDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tab_cust")

spark.sql("""
  SELECT tab_product.cust_id, nvl2(tab_cust.cust_id, 'Eligible', 'Not Eligible') as Eligibility
  FROM tab_product LEFT OUTER JOIN tab_cust
   ON tab_product.cust_id = tab_cust.cust_id
  """).show()
```

gives:

```
+-------+------------+
|cust_id| Eligibility|
+-------+------------+
|      1|Not Eligible|
|      3|    Eligible|
|      2|    Eligible|
+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but then can I also use following if I dont want to use nvl2, and have multiple conditions to check like: SELECT tab_product.cust_id, case when (tab_cust.cust_id is not null and tab_cust.price > 2500) then 'Eligible' else 'Not Eligible' end as as Eligibility
  FROM tab_product LEFT OUTER JOIN tab_cust
   ON tab_product.cust_id = tab_cust.cust_id;